# Algorithmic complexity of iterative - recursive solution

Tags: recursive-algorithms

I had an exam of algorithms and data structures today and I was given an excercise I wasn't prepared for. The excercise was some pseudocode that we needed to extrapolate the time complexity out of.

The entire crux of the doubt lies on a particular part of the code :

```
recursive_call(int n){
 if(n > 1){
    int t = 0;
    for a in 1 to n do
       t = t + (a*2) * (a*3)

    for a in 1 to 7 do 
       acc = acc + recursive_call(n/3)
    return acc; 
 }
  else return n-1;
}
```

The first part is trivially linear : the loop is executed n times. The second part , me and the rest of my group are in disagreement.

According to some , the complexity is actually ***T(n) = T(n / 3) + O(n)***. The recursive call is not splitted in multiple calls on the same activation record , hence it's never divided , therefore ***T(n/3)*** is not multiplied by any a>1.

Personally, I think that it doesn't matter on which part of the input you're calling the recursion , as long as you are doing it multiple times , it counts. Therefore the function should be ***T(n) = 7T(n/3) + O(n)***, because the function gets called multiple times. The fact that the input is identical is irrelevant.

So we are at an impasse. Can anyone clear this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second variant is correct - complexity for this implementation satisfies $T(n) = 7 T(\frac{n}{3}) + O(n)$.

It's possible to optimize this implementation by making recursive call only once, but it will formally be another algorithm with different complexity.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. If you know, is there a formal mathematical explaination? I came up with one but I don't know if it satisfies:
**Since the recursion is called multiple times for a total of 7 , this adds up to T(n) = T(n/3) + T(n/3)..T(n/3)  = 7T(n/3) + O(n)**
Thanks again for the quick answer

Comment: To get totally formal answer we need to formalize our model of computations, which is very hard even for such simple algorithms. But if we implement this exactly algorithm in any standard language (which doesn't optimize away repeating calls), we will get 7 recursive calls, not one. Other way to think about it - assume function has a side effect (for example, it increments global counter). Such change probably shouldn't affect complexity, but now it's clear that we need multiply recursive calls.